# How to call WCF method from the SSRS?

Tags: wcf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am developing the SSRS report and wanted to consume the one method call of the WCF service. Suppose I have a service Url like `http:\\localhost\2014\security.svc` and wanted to consume  `string Encrypt(string data)` method from that service. 
Now I know how to use XML and Web service as the data source. I don't want that what I want is to call the web service to get the some values encrypted on the report so I can use the expression to set the encrypted values for the some fields. In case of confusion feel free to leave a comment. Any help would be great .

Comment: you can also use your wcf service as simple web reference as well and can make a call to wcf service

Comment: @AshokRathod I dont know how to do it in SSRS can you point me towards the right direction ?